# Adding SQLite Library -ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios5, connection

I am working on iOS5.I am new for SQLite. I have created database named `DemoDB.sqlite`
Now for making connection with database I have added `libsql3.0.dylib` -library for SQLite.

But I received an error. **"Error in readDataFromDatabase method"**

Which library should I add?

```
-(void) readDataFromDatabase
{
    sqlite3 *database;
}
```

The error I received is **"use of undeclared identifier database"**

Comment: Had u imported sqlite3.0 in your class?

Comment: Are you write this #import<sqlite3.0> ? ok then try to add another library libsqlite3.0dylib

Comment: Thank you..i have used sqlite3.h  main header file and its working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler cannot see the declaration of the sqlite 3 struct. Try importing or including the main SQLite3 API header file:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

or

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

Comment: yes..it is working now with main header file..."sqlite3.h"..Thnak you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Compiler cannot see the declaration of the sqlite3 library ,So you have to import it by

```
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
```

or

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

it will work after that .

Comment: wat is this #import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h", can U please explin